# How to compile template class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm getting error for every template class I use in my program. Even when I copied a solution from a website and try to compile it is giving error such as ,

```
set_prac.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
set_prac.cc:10:13: error: ‘it’ does not name a type
for (auto it = std::begin(foo); it!=std::end(foo); ++it)
         ^
set_prac.cc:10:35: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
for (auto it = std::begin(foo); it!=std::end(foo); ++it)
                               ^
set_prac.cc:10:35: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
set_prac.cc:10:39: error: ‘end’ is not a member of ‘std’
for (auto it = std::begin(foo); it!=std::end(foo); ++it)
```

..................
..................

The program is ,
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/begin/

and it is running fine in their website . Is there any extra feature needed to compile C++ code that have template ?

I am compiling it as ,

g++ example.cc

Comment: `auto` for type deduction is C++11.

Comment: You have to use correct versioned gcc that supports c++11 features

Comment: try typing `g++ -std=c++11 example.cc`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others in the comment, if you're using C++11 features you need to include `-std=c++11` since gcc assumes c++03 by default. Depending on which version of gcc you're using, you may need to use `-std=c++0x` instead:

```
g++ -pedantic -std=c++0x example.cc -o example
```